# adb shell "watch" command to monitor

Tags: android, adb, mksh

I am trying to monitor some commands in my adb shell and I could go `watch adb shell <command>` but the extra time to have to connect up to the shell is killing me.

Does the Android `adb shell` have its own version of `watch` so I can monitor some commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while true; do <command>; sleep 2; done`